# Do mission ratings in Assassin's Creed IV actually go back to Ubisoft?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

At the end of each mission in Assassin's Creed IV, players have the opportunity to rate the mission.  Does this feedback actually go back to Ubisoft?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Ubisoft collects this data to get feedback on which missions are most favoured by players.

[In an interview with NowGamer](http://www.nowgamer.com/news/2145681/assassins_creed_4_black_flag_best_mission_revealed_by_ubisoft.html) Jonathan Dankoff, Ubisoft Motreal User Research Project Manager, said:

> "Ubisoft is actually using all of this data to improve future games."
>
> "Ubisoft has been using data tracking to improve our titles for a while, but this is the first time we will be able to match gameplay metrics to player appreciation in order to dig even deeper into player behavior."
>
> "The combination of the two data sources will give us incredible insight into how players are interacting with our game and guide future development teams to create missions that appeal to our players even more."

Comment: Hmmm... I assumed it was abstergo asking so I just acted like an abstergo toady and gave five stars (when I could be bothered to do anything).